# Image Gallery in Fragment not working (Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am trying to create image gallery in fragment but its not working.when i run the app its showing white screen in my emulater but there is no error in my logcat. i am using this tutorial for reference [tutorial](http://www.androidinterview.com/android-gallery-view-example-displaying-a-list-of-images/).this is my code

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, AttributeSet attrs, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagegallery, container, false);



     Gallery gallery = (Gallery) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
     gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
     gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View v, int position, long id) {
             Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), "pic" + (position + 1) + " selected",
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             // display the images selected
             ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
             imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
         }
     });
     return rootView;
 }

 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     private Context context;
     private int itemBackground;
     public ImageAdapter(Activity activity) {
             // sets a grey background; wraps around the images
             TypedArray a = getActivity().obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.MyGallery);
             itemBackground = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
             a.recycle();
         }
         // returns the number of images
     public int getCount() {
             return imageIDs.length;
         }
         // returns the ID of an item
     public Object getItem(int position) {
             return position;
         }
         // returns the ID of an item
     public long getItemId(int position) {
             return position;
         }
         // returns an ImageView view
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
         imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
         imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(100, 100));
         imageView.setBackgroundResource(itemBackground);
         return imageView;

     }


 }


 }
```

what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should `return rootView;` in your `Fragment` in `onCreateView(...)`

```
return rootView;
```

and remove

```
 super.onInflate(attrs, savedInstanceState);
```

and also change

```
 gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

to

```
 gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity());
```

Comment: i dont know its showing blank screen.i think its small mistake

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

public HomeFragment(){}
private Gallery gallery;
private ListView listview;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    gallery = (Gallery) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
    listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    gallery.setAdapter(new GalleryViewAdapter(getActivity()));
    String values[] ={"item1","item2","item1","item2"};
    ArrayList<String> listValue = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++){
        listValue.add(values[i]);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fly_in_from_center1);
    gallery.setAnimation(anim);
    anim.start();

    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            //view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_bg_pressed);
            Animation vanish =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.vanish);
            view.startAnimation(vanish);

            Log.i("pos :: ","pos :: "+position);
            //Toast.makeText(gridView.getContext(), "pos :: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
  }
}
```

this is Adapter

```
public class GalleryViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
public GalleryViewAdapter(Context c) {
    context = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 15;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v;

      if (convertView == null) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row,null);
        v.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(250,250));
      }
      else {
        v = convertView;
      }
      ImageView imageview = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.row_img);
      TextView txtview = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
      txtview.setText("Hello"+position);
      imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
      imageview.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6);
      return v;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

getActivity() is working inside of pageadapter         .

```
GalleryAdapter pageAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(getActivity(), proName, proImage);

ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)getView().findViewById(R.id.galery);

pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
```